# How to reference layout images in express.js so that they can be found from nested directories?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, ejs

I've got an express.js app currently using ejs (using jade for newer projects) and I'm trying to solve a problem in a clean and appropriate manner.

I've got a layout.ejs file with my header and footer in it. Most of my site so far has been one layer deep http://innovationbound.com/about or /services or /amy and so on....

I'm beginning to created online courses at http://innovationbound.com/courses/course-name and the issue I'm having is that these course pages can't reference the images the same way. `<img src="images/linknedin.png" alt="LinkedIn Icon">` for instance.

From the course-name page it tries `<img src="courses/images/LinkedIn.png" alt="LinkedIn Icon">` and obviously can't grab the image there.

Is there a setting in express, or something obvious I'm missing? I hope I don't have to use absolute urls, that just makes developing on the local machine insane.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use site root–relative paths. For example `<img src="/images/linknedin.png" alt="LinkedIn Icon">`. Note the `/` makes the difference.

> There are three types of link paths:
>
> - Absolute paths (such as http://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/contents.html).
> - Document-relative paths (such as dreamweaver/contents.html).
> - Site root–relative paths (such as /support/dreamweaver/contents.html).

From [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c44a.html#WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c42a).

Comment: this killed me. you save me.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider it, but you can use "../images/link(n?)edin.png". However, I'd recommend to use absolute path, because images should be stored in /public (in general jade setup) and your path depth could be varied by your route rule.

As a tip, if you lost in relative path of image, right click on broken image and see a URL in properties on web browser. It'll give you a hint of where the image is.

Comment: Thanks for trying : ) I can't use the absolute path because it'll be localhost sometimes and on the server other times. Also, if I do "../images" then the rest of my routes would fail to go to the right place since I'm using a layout.ejs as a template for all pages.