# How to load image path correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, styled-components

I have the folder structure like the following.

```
src/
    components/
        Icon/
            Icon.js
            Style.js

    images/
        apple.svg
        google.svg
        facebook.svg
        index.js
```

I want to export the paths of images under images folder in 'images/index.js'.

I tried something like this below.

## images/index.js

```
export const apple = './apple.svg';
export { google } from './google.svg';
export const facebook = './facebook.svg';
```

And I want to load the paths of those images in '/Components/Icon/Style.js' like the following.

## Style.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

// I know this works fine
import apple from '../../images/apple.svg';

// This doesn't work although I want it to work.
import { google } from '../../images/index';

// This doesn't work as well although I want it to work.
import { facebook } from '../../images/index';


const Icon = styled.i`
    background: blah blah blah  
`;


export default Icon;
```

However, I couldn't load the paths of images.

What is the right way to do that?

Is it impossible?

`export const apple = './apple.svg';`

Is this the only way I can load the path of image?

Comment: The example you have for facebook looks like it should work. You have an export (non default) and then a named import. What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: I don't get any error but the path loaded is incorrect when I check it in the developer tool. 
background: url(./facebook.svg)

Comment: What I'm exporting is just a string of the path to the image, so that happens... export const closeBt = './close_bt.svg';

Comment: Ok so the problem isn't that the import doesn't work, it's that your relative path is no longer correct based on the location of the file that it is now in. You'll want to use site-root relative paths like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736981/how-to-reference-layout-images-in-express-js-so-that-they-can-be-found-from-nest

Comment: Here is maybe a more relevant stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## images/index.js

```
import apple from './apple.svg';
import google from './google.svg';
import facebook from './facebook.svg';

export {
  apple,
  google,
  facebook
}
```

## Style.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { apple, google, facebook } from '../../images';

const Icon = styled.i`
    background: blah blah blah  
`;

export default Icon;
```

#### This should work, and also looks pretty clean code to my eyes!

---

## A Recomendation

Requesting an image for every "icon" to your server feels really expensive.
Instead, since you have access to the resources I would go with this structure:

```
src/
    components/
        Icon/
            Apple.js
            Google.js
            Facebook.js
```

### Facebook.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Facebook({ width = '266', height = '266' } = {}) {
  return (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width={width} height={height} viewBox="0 0 266.893 266.895" enableBackground="new 0 0 266.893 266.895">
      <path
        fill="#3C5A99"
        d="M248.082,262.307c7.854,0,14.223-6.369,14.223-14.225V18.812  c0-7.857-6.368-14.224-14.223-14.224H18.812c-7.857,0-14.224,6.367-14.224,14.224v229.27c0,7.855,6.366,14.225,14.224,14.225  H248.082z"
      />
      <path
        fill="#FFFFFF"
        d="M182.409,262.307v-99.803h33.499l5.016-38.895h-38.515V98.777c0-11.261,3.127-18.935,19.275-18.935  l20.596-0.009V45.045c-3.562-0.474-15.788-1.533-30.012-1.533c-29.695,0-50.025,18.126-50.025,51.413v28.684h-33.585v38.895h33.585  v99.803H182.409z"
      />
    </svg>
  );
}

export default Facebook;
```

Advantages:

- No network request
- Reusable icon
- Customizable with states (colors, shapes, etc)